# Find TDs with certain class within TRs with certain class

Tags: jquery, html, loops, each

I am trying to get the HTML of all TDs with a certain class within TRs with a certain class. 
So far I have the following but this doesnt work.

**Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?**

```
$('#queueTable').find('tr.trSel').each(function() {
    html += "<tr>";
    $(this).find('td.tdSel').each(function() {
        html += $(this).html();
    });
    html += "</tr>";
});
```

Comment: Sample HTML (e.g. in a JSFiddle) would make this nice :) The selectors look OK at first glance.

Comment: `html` is declared outside of this method, correct?

Comment: Yes, html is declared outside.

Comment: It seems my issue is to find the TDs with the certain class as their HTML does not appear in the output.

Comment: Which part of this doesn't work? What are you expecting and what is the actual output?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I cant post the HTML as this is too much data for here.

Comment: Yep. Test output is like `"<tr>TD 1</tr><tr>TD 2</tr>"`. Missing TD element as Paul Roub says: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/UK6Vz/1/

Comment: well the `td` was never added to the html variable. Such a simple problem if OP listed which part of this did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will create `<tr>` objects with just the *contents* of the `<td>` cells, but no actual `<td>` tags.

Try:

```
$('#queueTable').find('tr.trSel').each(function() {
    html += "<tr>";
    $(this).find('td.tdSel').each(function() {
        html += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
    });
    html += "</tr>";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Let me check !

Comment: The TD tags was what was missing - works great ! Thanks again - will accept as soon as I can. :)

Comment: Then why loop the the `<td>`'s at all?? Just get the html of the row. `html += "<tr>" + $(this).html() + "</tr>"`

Comment: Selecting *certain* cells out of those rows (and removing classes along the way). Your version gets *all* of the cells.